# Argument with Noether's Normalization Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra of finite type, where $k$ is a field, and suppose that $A$ is an integral domain. Noether's normalization states that exists a finite injection of $k$-algebras $\iota:k[x_1,\dots,x_d]\hookrightarrow A$ (the $x_1,\dots,x_d$ are variables). The task is to prove that $\operatorname{Frac}A$ is finite over the field $k(x_1,\dots,x_d)$, and deduce that $d$ equals the transcendence degree of $\operatorname{Frac}A$ over $k$.

First, if $S:=k[x_1,\dots,x_d]-\{0\}$, we know that $k(x_1,\dots,x_d)\hookrightarrow \iota(S)^{-1}A$ is finite again. Since any finite homomorphism is integral, we have that $S^{-1}A$ is a field, as the map above is an integral injection of integral domains. Now, localizing $A$ at some multiplicatively closed subset, in general gives raise to an integral domain contained in $\operatorname{Frac}A$, so $S^{-1}A\subseteq \operatorname{Frac}A$; but since $S^{-1}A$ is a field it contains $\operatorname{Frac}A$, so we obtain that $k(x_1,\dots,x_d)\hookrightarrow \operatorname{Frac}A$ is finite (and so algebraic). In order to conclude, notice that $$\operatorname {Trdeg}(\operatorname{Frac}A/k)=\operatorname {Trdeg}(\operatorname{Frac}A/k(x_1,\dots,x_d))+\operatorname {Trdeg}(k(x_1,\dots,x_d)/k)=0+d.$$

Is this argument correct? Did I miss to check anything? Thanks in  advance.

Comment: This looks correct to me, although I can’t see precisely why $S^{-1}A$ being a field follows *precisely* from the facts quoted to support it (“integral injection”, basically), but that may just be because we probably weren’t introduced in the same way to commutative algebra. Minor nitpick: don’t use $k$ and $K$ for the same thing. I’d also tentatively suggest to use $\mathrm{Trdeg}(k(x_1,\ldots,x_d)/k)$ instead of the other way around.

Comment: @Mindlack forgive me if I've misunderstood your comment, but it follows because if $A \subset B$ is an integral extension of domains, then $A$ is a field iff $B$ is a field. For the direction we care about in this proof, for any nonzero $y \in B$, find a monic $f \in A[X]$ with $f(y) = 0$ such that the constant term $a$ is nonzero (always possible because $B$ is a domain), and then note that $y((f(y)-a)/y) \cdot (-a^{-1}) = 1$. See, e.g., Prop 5.7 in Atiyah-Macdonald.

Comment: @Mindlack sorry for the errors of notation, I should have eliminated them. For your first observation, I used the result mentioned by Alex Wertheim (I took it from Bosch's Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra, 3.1.2)

Comment: @Alex Wertheim: how can I put it best? I know that this result is true and I do know its proof (and I believed the author knew it too) – but it’s not easy to say how “standard” it is to be able to cite the hypotheses and deduce the conclusion “like that” (for instance, find at a technical lemma somewhere deep in Stacks Project – would you use it as informally? If not, can you draw a universal line?) – which depends of course on the precise way the topic was studied. I believed it was worth investigating it further.

Comment: @Mindlack I suspected so, but I figured I'd post a proof just in case. Thanks for explaining your thoughts.